# JSON Array for jQuery UI Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete

The task is to get local JSON file with array of city names and put them to autocomplete. There is no info exactly about JSON arrays, always talk about pairs 'key'-'value'. So I have a question: is it possible to use arrays with single items in JSON and if it is where is the mistake of my code?
**JSON**

```
    [
    "Minsk",
    "London",
    "Riga",
    "Vilnius",
    "Warszaw",
    "Paris",
    "Moscow",
    "Tallin",
    "Berlin",
    "Amsterdam",
    "Oslo",
    "Helsinki"
]
```

**JS**

```
$('#tags').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var result = $.ajax({
            url: '../source.json',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                var array = [];
                response($.each( data, function(item) {
                    array.push(item);
                    return array;
                }));
                return array;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you post what the javascript error is? You can look at the console in your browser dev tools.

Comment: The worst is that there is no errors

Comment: I would try to navigate to the `source.json` file. If this works, make `../source.json` an absolute path and see if your AJAX call will work. In your success function I would put in a `console.log(data)` statement so you can see what is being returned from the URL.

Comment: "local JSON file" - if you're loading/attempting to read files straight from your machine (ie with `file://`), this is unlikely to work.  As soon as you move beyond basic development, you usually need to serve files as though they came from a webserver

Comment: @Mark I added absolute path, success function doesn't work: the message is that data is not defined

Comment: I know that it doesn't work in chrome. OK, thank u, I'll try with server or fiddler)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON does support arrays as well as objects.

Your code doesn't return the result to the source. In fact, you can't wait for $.ajax() to finish at all without using a `setInterval` to check it or the like. The best method is to access the JSON file once when the page loads and reference the source from there.

Try:

```js
var dict = [];

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100496307/source.json',
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {
      dict.push(this.toString());
    });
    return dict;
  }
});

$('#tags').autocomplete({
  source: dict
});

$('#tags').keydown(function() {
  console.log(dict);
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="tags" />
</body>
```

Comment: I've changed location of file JSON and tried your solution - there is no reaction( [json now is here] (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/100496307/source.json)

Comment: Fixed. Try the snippet.

Comment: Thanks! It works! There was mistake with editing json for autocomplete, right?  Please explain what does line 'complete = true;' and why do you write '(function() {
    return dict;
  })()' instead of 'function() {
    return dict;
  }'?

Comment: The mistake was that you were trying to use a source array that didn't exist yet (it had to grab it with AJAX). The current code will use an empty array if the AJAX hasn't loaded but will use the AJAX array if it has loaded. `completed` is from an earlier attempt. Removed it now.

Comment: I used the function call because I thought it wouldn't dynamically grab dict every time you typed and would only use the value of dict from when you first bound `.autocomplete()`, but I just tested it and that was wrong. I'll remove that as well. Good catch.